# Get data type for a QGIS 3 RasterLayer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

How do I use python to find raster layers data type

The raster data type for a band like *float32* or *int16*?

I know you can use `rasterlayer.dataType(1)` but how do I then lookup returned integer (eg 6)  and get the data type?

I'm currently using QGIS 3.10

Comment: Find GDAL Driver for raster layer is now a new post  [gdal-driver-from-qgis-3-raster-layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367977/gdal-driver-from-qgis-3-raster-layer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qgis class provides global constants for use throughout the application. So, if you print in QGIS Python Console:

```
>>>Qgis.Float32
6
>>>Qgis.Float64
7
```

you will get its respective data type expressed as integer. In these cases, you can build a dictionary like this:

```
>>>dataTypes = {6:'Float32', 7:'Float64'}
```

and you can print the data type as follows:

```
>>>dataTypes[6]
'Float32'
>>>dataTypes[7]
'Float64'
```

You can complete the dictionary for all possible data types by searching all possible results in enumerate group:

```
>>>Qgis.Int16
3
>>>Qgis.Int32
5
.
.
.
```

Complete information about data types can be observed in this link:

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/Qgis.html