# GDAL Driver from QGIS 3 Raster Layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

How do I use python to find raster layer properties like

The GDAL driver and/or description used to load a raster in QGIS

For Example : for a Tif '*GTiff'* and *'GeoTiff'* or 
       for an ESRI Grid *'AIG'* and *'Arc/Info Binary Grid'*

For a vectors you use `layer.dataProvider().storageType()` but when applied to a raster layer it returns `AttributeError: 'QgsRasterDataProvider' object has no attribute 'storageType'`

I'm using QGIS 3.10

Answer (score 2):

QGIS uses GDAL behind the scene and only exposes infos as HTML e.g `iface.activeLayer().htmlMetadata()`. So to get the infos, I would use the following:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

layer = iface.activeLayer()
dataset = gdal.Open(layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri(), gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

print(dataset.GetDriver().ShortName)
print(dataset.GetDriver().LongName)
```